# Deploying docker to AWS without load balancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I create software solutions for customers and I usually deploy 2 environments for each customer: QA and production. I am using ECS to deploy containers and cloudfront to deploy static websites.

Some of my customers dont require the scalability and overhead of ECS. I also dont require it for the QA environments. The end result is that for a solution with 2 ECS clusters I pay x5 then my actual usage (35$ for load balancer usage, extras for fargate instances etc)

Is there a way I can simply deploy a container into a single instance without scalability and without load balancing so my monthly bill will simply include the 10$ (t2.nano) I pay for running EC2 instance?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, simply deploy your ECS service on an EC2 instance (EC2 launch type) without configuring a load balancer or auto scaling. It's not like you have to do something to *not* get these features. You have to do something *to* use these features, so simply don't configure them. In order to get domain name access to your service, you could then use a simple Route 53 A record to your EC2 instance or use AWS Cloud Map.